# HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session for bigger result set

Tags: java, hibernate, session, jpa

I have application that is using JPA 2.0 and Hibernate as the persistence provider. I am using EntityManager to build my queries.

I am expericing the classic `org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session` error on the big set of data. When I am trying to extract just a few Datapoints it is working correctly, but once I am extracting 30+ results I am getting `org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session` error. I thought I should not get it since I am using `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Here are two of my entities.
DatapointView:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DATAPOINT_VIEW")
public class DatapointView implements Serializable {
    ...many fields...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinColumn(name = "EXPERIMENT_ID",  referencedColumnName = "EXPERIMENT_ID")
    private List<ExperimentViewEntity> experiments= new ArrayList<ExperimentViewEntity>();
    ...
}
```

ExperimentViewEntity:

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "EXPERIMENT_VIEW")
public class ExperimentViewEntity {
    ...many fields...
@Column(name = "EXPERIMENT_ID", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 36)
    private String experimentId;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have a still open transaction when interaction with the DatapointView object. Eager Fetching is probably not a solution for that. Also the hibernate documentation say you should not do it in that way please see the documentation for OneToMany -> http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association

When you expect to have a large amount of data in that list you should consider move the relation to the ExperimentViewEntity (unidirectional). And query for the ExperimentViewEntities when needed. This does also allow to do pagination, which may be necessary in terms of performance.